# Change brightness in frequency domain

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft, frequency

I probably did not understand how frequency domain works. For a project I have to change the brightness of an image with Python and without working in the spatial domain.

At the moment I can apply some blur filters through convolution, as in the example below:

```
 def arithmeticMeanFilter(self, img):

    img = img.convert('RGB')
    open_cv_image = np.array(img)
    red = open_cv_image[:, :, 0]
    green = open_cv_image[:, :, 1]
    blue = open_cv_image[:, :, 2]

    mean_arithmetic = np.ones((9, 9))*(1/81)

    width, height, _ = open_cv_image.shape

    kernel1 = np.zeros((width, height))
    kernel1[:mean_arithmetic.shape[0], :mean_arithmetic.shape[1]] = mean_arithmetic
    kernel1 = np.fft.fft2(kernel1)


    im = np.array(red)
    fim = np.fft.fft2(im)
    Rx = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(kernel1 * fim)).astype(float)

    im = np.array(green)
    fim = np.fft.fft2(im)
    Gx = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(kernel1 * fim)).astype(float)

    im = np.array(blue)
    fim = np.fft.fft2(im)
    Bx = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(kernel1 * fim)).astype(float)

    open_cv_image[:, :, 0] = abs(Rx)
    open_cv_image[:, :, 1] = abs(Gx)
    open_cv_image[:, :, 2] = abs(Bx)

    img = Image.fromarray(open_cv_image)

    return img
```

But how can I change brightness using this technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing brightness in an image is accomplished by multiplying each pixel by a constant.

Because the [Fourier transform is a linear operation](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html), multiplying by a constant in the spatial domain is equivalent to multiplying by the same constant in the frequency domain.

Linearity of a function *F* is defined as:

*aF(x) + bF(y) = F(ax + by)*

From that equation it is easy to show *aF(x) = F(ax)*, or, as I stated above, multiplying in one domain is equivalent to multiplying in the other.

[kmario23 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844897/change-brightness-in-frequency-domain-with-python/54844952?noredirect=1#comment96467550_54844952) that multiplication in the frequency domain is convolution in the spatial domain. This is true. But since we’re dealing with a constant, things are a bit simpler. In any case, one can see that a constant function in the frequency domain is an [impulse (or dirac delta) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) in the spatial domain. Convolving with an impulse function is the same as multiplying by a constant.

Going to the frequency domain for a change in brightness is wasteful, but if you’re already there you can do it this way.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "multiplication in Fourier domain is equivalent to convolution in the spatial domain"?